# Custom query for Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The basic DRF setup for my little Podcast Backend is working quite well:

```
router.register(r'episodes', views.EpisodeViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

in urls.py

and

```
class EpisodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # show = ShowSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Episode
        depth = 1


class EpisodeDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chapters = ChapterMarkSerializer(source='chaptermark_set', many=True)
    media = MediaClipSerializer(source='mediaclip_set', many=True)
    show = ShowSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Episode
        depth = 1
```

in serializers.py as well as

```
class EpisodeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Episode.objects.all().order_by('-published_at')

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return EpisodeDetailSerializer
        return EpisodeSerializer
```

work well for creating a full episode list (I chopped down the classes a bit, they do additionally contain some field filters but this is not related) and also for a hyperlinked Detail view for each episode.

Additionally to that I need the possibility to query episodes by other fields. Especially a "number" field and the "show_id"

I can't seem to get behind how this is done in DRF. I already tried adding def get_queryset() to the EpisodeDetailSerializer Class but that didn't work.

So what I'm looking for is to process something like

```
/api/episodes/?show_id=2&number=24
```

to deliver episode details instead of the default

```
/api/episodes/123
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`django_filters`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend):

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class EpisodeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Episode.objects.all().order_by('-published_at')
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('show_id', 'number')

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve' or self.request.GET.get('show_id') and self.request.GET.get('number'):
            return EpisodeDetailSerializer
        return EpisodeSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks, this basically works already. There's just one problem: This only affects the list view of all episodes. The EpisodeDetailSerializer comes in place through that 'retrieve' action - at least that's what I think, I'm really just digging into this slowly. And what I would need is to get the detail Serializer returned for the episode filtered by show_id and number.

Comment: @Helmi you can try to check in `get_serializer_class`  `self.request.GET.get('show_id') and self.request.GET.get('number')` also.